# Googlebot - Not Seeing Mobile Version - Not Mobile Friendly

Tags: mobile

I have a website with the Response Header Vary set to "User-Agent". I have verified that none of the JavaScript or CSS code is blocked using the Fetch as Google tool. When looking at the Rendering tab for Googlebot type Mobile:Smartphone it is showing that Googlebot is seeing the normal web version and not the mobile version. It also shows on the Rendering tab that the visitor would have seen the page showing the mobile version correctly.

Google is showing my website as not mobile friendly. But, there is a very nice mobile version of the website for mobile that comes up when I visit with my iPhone or use the Google Chrome simulator. Also, I am not using a second URL for my mobile version (m.mysite.com).

We are using the [Mobile Device Detector](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/mobile_device_detector.aspx) module for detecting a mobile device.

Our Sitecore version is: Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003).

Do I have to convert my website using Bootstrap in order to get Googlebot to see my mobile version and consider my site mobile friendly? It has been suggested that I change the site to use [Separate URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls).

Here are the response Headers:

[image]

Here is the rule which sends the Mobile version.

[image]

Here is the Google Mobile Usability Report:

[image]

Here is the Google Mobile-Friendly Test:

[image]

The Screen Width Rule Element for Device Detection points to:

```
Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector.Rules.Conditions.ScreenWidthCondition, Sitecore.SharedSource.MobileDeviceDetector
```

**Edit:**

Here is the version of 51Degrees we are using. 51Degrees emailed us to say that the version we are using is no longer supported and that we should look into using [3Chillies](http://www.3chillies.co.uk/blog/2015/09/3chillies-brings-51degrees-device-detection-to-sitecore).

[image]

Comment: Ignore my close flag. Might be good for someone to expand on how devices work in site core.

Comment: Could you detail what the rule is doing to detect the screen size, with some code if you have it? How are you doing the device detection?

Comment: Have you run the Mobile Friendly Test and checked the Mobile Usability Report? https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/11/helping-users-find-mobile-friendly-pages.html

Comment: @jammykam I updated the question with screenshots of both.

Comment: @IanGraham I'm not exactly sure how the device detection is done. I thought the rule did that based on width. How can I find out what code is used?

Comment: I added the class used for device detection to the question.

Comment: In the Google "mobile friendly" test does the screen shot of the site look correct? That is, is the bot seeing the mobile view or the desktop view? Have you got robots.txt blocking something critical?  Also looking at the [Marketplace "MobileDeviceDetector" library](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/mobile_device_detector.aspx) there is a recent (v4) version that has support for recent changes to the 51Degrees support library, and the ScreenWidthCondition has been made "internal".  I suspect you need to update your module.

Comment: The screenshot is showing the desktop view, not the mobile view. I do not think robots.txt is blocking anything critical.

Comment: You're using the Mobile Device Detector from the Sitecore Marketplace, which uses 51Degrees.mobi - As I understand it, you need a subscription or something to activate it. Do you have one?

Comment: I will see if I can find out about a subscription.

Comment: Also, if you want to find out how it (the Sitecore module) works, the code is here: https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Mobile-Device-Detector

Comment: I am being told that we were told by the vendor that 51Degrees is built into Sitecore.

Comment: Sitecore version please. Also, are you licensed for XDB/DMS/OMS?

Comment: Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46640/discussion-between-sergeant-sitecore-and-adh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Googlebot to the Browser Agent and the site is now coming up as mobile-friendly on the Google Mobile-Friendly Test page.

[image]